# (python) os.path.exists os.path.isfile lies?

Tags: python, windows, path

os.path.exists is giving me incorrect answers.

it's not the same problem discussed at below link since I'm at windows.
Are there other reasons for it to fail?

[os.path.exists() lies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112546/os-path-exists-lies)

The test returns ok when I test it against a file at the same directory as the *.py script runs, but none of its sub directories..

-EDIT-

I'm using absolute path.

I'm looking at one of the sub directories as this script runs,       and can literally see file's last modified time field being changed in the windows explorer.
There are no other stuff going on my computer I can think of that will modify the files in question.

```
def SaveIfNewer(doc, aiFile, pngFile):
    options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Illustrator.ExportOptionsPNG24')
    options.SetArtBoardClipping(True)
    if (os.path.exists(pngFile)):
        aiFileTime = os.stat(aiFile)[8]
        pngFileTime = os.stat(pngFile)[8]
        print("aiFileTime: ", aiFileTime, "pngFileTime: ", pngFileTime)

        if(aiFileTime > pngFileTime):
            os.remove(pngFile)

    if( not os.path.isfile(pngFile)):
        doc.Export(pngFile, constants.aiPNG24, options)
        print 'exporting:', pngFile
    else:
        print 'skipping file:', pngFile
```

Comment: What are these incorrect answers? What makes your problem different from the problem in the link? Can you show us your code and a sample directory layout?

Comment: are you using absolute or relative paths? If relative, check the return from getcwd()

Answer (score 3):

`os.path.exists` and `os.path.isfile` is not case sensitive in Windows machines.

Here's what I get in Windows 7 (Python 2.7)

```
>>> os.path.exists('C:/.rnd')
True
>>> os.path.exists('C:/.RND')
True
>>> os.path.isfile('C:/.rnd')
True
>>> os.path.isfile('C:/.RND')
True
```

Comment: Could be different versions, I have some vague memory of this being discussed on python-dev.

Comment: i tested with c:\a\B\c.txt and c:\a\b\c.txt and gave me different results

Answer (score 1):

Turned out, os.path.exists and os.path.isfile is case-sensitive..

Blah!